# How to setup protectionController/ProtectionData in dash.js v2

Tags: javascript, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I want to play a protected video using `dash.js`. I’m using dash v2.0 and it's completely different from v1. the below code which work in v1 no longer works in v2.

```
$(function() {
    var AXINOM_DEMO_WV_LS = "http://axpr-wv-fe.cloudapp.net:8080/LicensingService";

    var context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
    var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
    player.startup();
    player.attachView(document.querySelector('#videoPlayer'));
    player.attachProtectionData({"com.widevine.alpha": new MediaPlayer.vo.protection.ProtectionData(AXINOM_DEMO_WV_LS)});

    $('#playButton').click(function() {
        var videoUrl = 'http://level3-cdn.axprod.net/demo/manifestprot.ism/.mpd';
        player.attachSource(videoUrl);
    });
});
```

I have tried to rewrite it again in v2

```
$(function() {
    var AXINOM_DEMO_WV_LS = "http://axpr-wv-fe.cloudapp.net:8080/LicensingService";
    var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
    player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"),"", true);
    player.attachProtectionData({"com.widevine.alpha": new ProtectionData(AXINOM_DEMO_WV_LS)});
    $('#playButton').click(function() {
        var videoUrl = 'http://level3-cdn.axprod.net/demo/manifestprot.ism/.mpd';
        player.attachSource(videoUrl);
    });
});
```

But it's not working. an error is being thrown.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ProtectionData is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:5)
```

I don't know how to correctly define this protection data since there is no tutorial on how to do it. kindly assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem. In dash.js version 2, this is the way protectionData is set.

```
var AXINOM_DEMO_WV_LS = "http://axpr-wv-fe.cloudapp.net:8080/LicensingService";
var drmKeySystem ="com.widevine.alpha";
var protData ={drmKeySystem:{serverURL: AXINOM_DEMO_WV_LS}};

 var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
 player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"),"", true);
 player.setProtectionData(protData);
```